# Android AsyncTask with Handler

Tags: android, android-asynctask, orientation, handler

I am working on an android app where i need to download some images and start a slide show.
For downloading the images i am using a AsynTask, as soon as the images are downloaded i am using an handler to start the slide show. But during orientation change i am not able to control the handler. Because the handler object is defined with AsyncTask class.

The below is the rough scenario of what i have done:

**Class A extends Activity**

Class B  async = new ClassB(this);

async.execute();

**Class B extends AsyncTask implements OnPageChangeListener, OnTouchListener**

onPreExecute() -------Nothing in this method

doInBackground -------I am downloading the images here

onPostExecute ---------Handler starts here and runs for every 5 seconds for implementing Slide Show

**Now the Problem:**

During orientation change i have made sure that AsyncTask is called only once or else it downloads the images again, because of this the handler is not running during orientation change.

The first handler object which was started, it keeps running but the changes does not reflect on the screen.

I was thinking of implementing in a way that the images are downloaded by using the AsyncTask and once the downloading is done, ClassA should gain focus and handler should be implemented in ClassA(only when images are downloaded).

Comment: Make a interface method in your class B..and after download completion..(in onPostExecution) Told your interface that download  completed. and do the slide show work in your download complete listener.

Comment: I did not get it, can you give me rough example of it

Comment: _During orientation change i have made sure that AsyncTask is called only once or else it downloads the images again, because of this the handler is not running during orientation change._ You'd better explain more on this (may be with some code sample), to give us more clear picture about your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The Interface class naming is according to my case. Please adjust it according to your rquirments. `ArtikelDetailsDataLoader` my Async task. Which tell my activity that details are loaded.

in your Class B

```
public interface OndetailsLoadInterface {
    public void onDetailsLoad(ArtikelDetailsInfo artikelDetails);
}

OndetailsLoadInterface detailsLoaderInterface;

public void setOnDetailsLoadListener(OndetailsLoadInterface detailsLoader) {
    detailsLoaderInterface = detailsLoader;
}
```

and in `onPostExecute`

`detailsLoaderInterface.onDetailsLoad(artikelDetails);`

and in class A

`ArtikelDetailsDataLoader mLoader = new ArtikelDetailsDataLoader(
                            items.get(position).getId(), mContext);
                    mLoader.setOnDetailsLoadListener(mLoaderLisnter);`

and

```
OndetailsLoadInterface mLoaderLisnter = new OndetailsLoadInterface() {

        @Override
        public void onDetailsLoad(ArtikelDetailsInfo artikelDetails) {
            //do slide show

        }

    };
```

Comment: Thanks i will implement it and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Just make a method in your `Activity` called `startSlideShow(position)` that you call from your `onPostExecute()` method, with `startSlideShow(0)`.

On orientation change save your current slide show position, and your downloaded images, and then in your `onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)` then start the slideshow from the previous position using `startSlideShow(restoredPosition);`.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is caused by the Activity restarting when orientation changes, have you considered setting android:configChanges="orientation" in your AndroidManifest.xml entry for the activity, which should prevent the restarts?

Then, if you need to perform any updates to the UI (e.g. switching to a different layout), you can handle onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) and implement it yourself.

Comment: I have done that but the layout remains fixed, i have a different layout for landscape mode. The landscape layout is not loaded if i use the configChanges tag

Comment: You would need to call setContentView again, and reinitialise the contents of your controls, to ensure the new layout is loaded.

Comment: But if i do that then i have to call AsyncTask again, which is not a good idea. Also, when the async task is actually in execution mode and when there is an orientation change it can cause problems.

Comment: If you just change the layout without restarting the AsyncTask, everything should be fine (as long as the AsyncTask doesn't hold a reference to any of your controls -- if it does, simply make it check they're valid and reacquire then in onPostExecute).